# Which is the most popular and crowded chess server?

Tags: software, online-chess, computer-chess, online

Which is the most popular and crowded chess server? I'm new at computer chess, and want to start playing at servers, but I do not understand where I have to play.

I am hearing about [freechess](https://www.freechess.org/), [chessclub](https://www.chessclub.com/), [lichess](https://lichess.org), [chess.com](http://chess.com/).

How do I play in chess servers? Will I use a GUI or will I play directly in the browser. How do the professionals play?

Mention that, I like free and open-source things.

Comment: "Which is the most popular and crowded chess server?" You are asking the wrong question. The correct question is: "Which chess website would I enjoy playing the most on?" And the answer is - make a free account on any of them and see for yourself.

Comment: *How do the professionals play?* - I doubt that actual professionals play online at all. There are too many ways to cheat at online chess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lichess has everything you need. Free and open source. It's the second or third popular website after chess.com (possibly chess24 not sure). Many strong players. No installation as it’s a web app.

Comment: +1 because lichess is purely awesome. Just a note though, lichess does have a mobile app available, too.

Answer (score 0):

Fide is the federation site for international chess and their [Arena site](https://arena.myfide.net/) allows you to play online and even win titles like Arena Grand Master (AGM). It has resources and links to sites. It has statistics and world position lists of all rated players and is responsible for the chess Olympiad held every 2 years where countries compete. You can't become a Grandmaster unless fide rates you above a threshold

Comment: That's not a chess server, though.

Comment: @DM  FIDE's Online Arena server is a chess server.

Comment: @BrianTowers You're correct. But I've tried it, and it's *certainly* not "the most popular and crowded".